# Setting ASHIHTTPRequest to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsdictionary, asihttprequest

I'm trying to send an NSDictionary to a server and have it set up as follows:

```
NSDictionary *songInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:propertyValues forKeys:propertyKeys];

NSURL *exampleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/activities"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:exampleURL];

[request setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:songInfo];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[<ASIFormDataRequest 0x1035600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 1 Media Type.
```

Which is puzzling because Media Type is the 14th key in the Dictionary, so how could it have been fine with all the other ones and then flipped out on this?

It seems to not be accepting my Dictionary, but is there any reason why?

Comment: What are propertyvalues and propertykeys? What is inside of them? I've never tried using setValuesForKeysWithDictionary with an ASIFormDataRequest either, as that method comes from NSOperation. Have you tried just using addPostValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons:

- The keys in a dictionary are not ordered. There is no such thing as a "14th key in [a] Dictionary." The dictionary entries have to be serialized for logging, but there is no guarantee they will be accessed in the same order by other methods.
- Neither `ASIFormDataRequest` nor `ASIHTTPRequest` override `-setValueForKeysWithDictionary:` or `-setValue:forKey:`. This means that, unless the keys match up to key-value-coding–compliant keys of the object, you are going to see that exception.

Try using a supported method, like `-setPostValue:forKey:`:

```
NSDictionary *songInfo = /*...*/;
ASIFormDataRequest *request = /*...*/;
[songInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:
^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
    [request setPostValue:value forKey:key];
}];
```

And in future: USE [THE SOURCE](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/Classes).

Comment: So how can I easily get the contents of the dictionary into the request without assigning each Post and Key individually?

Comment: If you can update the web service to handle it, you can archive the dictionary to an `NSData` using `+[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:]`, which means everything in the dictionary has to conform to `NSCoding` and your web service has to have access to the same classes to decode the archive, or serialize the dictionary as a plist using the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class, which means everything in the dictionary has to be serialized using only plist types. Any web service should be able to deserialize an XML plist.

Comment: I don't want to send it via XML but as http variables. Would archiving still work for that?

Comment: Please provide a reference specifying "HTTP variables". Archiving doesn't really work for anything other than archiving to Apple's private format for archived objects.

Comment: I'm new to this whole "sending things to a server" thing and have no idea what HTTP variables are. I was just asked to send them as such and am thoroughly confused as to what that means. Sorry that I am so unhelpful.

Comment: It's not your fault. Garbage spec in, garbage code out. Throw the question back at whoever asked you to provide "HTTP variables". My guess would be they actually want a POST request containing keys and values formatted per the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. See for discussion [this tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial13/4.html) on the common HTML form content-types.

Comment: I would just use the `-setPostValue:forKey:` method of `ASIFormDataRequest`. If you want to see what doing this with `NSURLRequest` looks like, check out the [OAuthConsumer](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c/OAuthConsumer/) project for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Start by reading `-setParameters:` in `NSMutableURLRequest+Parameters.m` and go from there. For `multipart/form-data` with `NSURLRequest`, see Facebook's [`FBRequest`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.m#L105-165).